# Display user's result summary in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show the user's result summery. i.e. the questions He attempted and the result of their answer and also those questions he left unattended. I have one table containing question master and one table is answer master. I want to display the user's summery. Below is my table structure. Currently, I am getting only attempted Questions and their answers by the following query

```
SELECT t1.exam_type,t1.questions,a1.answer,t1.correct_ans FROM tbl_que t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_ans a1 ON a1.que_id=t1.que_id WHERE t1.exam_type='1' AND a1.user_id='001' ORDER BY t1.que_id
```

But I want unattempted questions also for the specific user.

```
tbl_que
que_id  |exam_type  |exam_name  |questions |correct_ans
1       |1          |railway    |que1      |ansA
2       |1          |railway    |que2      |ansC
3       |2          |post       |que3      |ansC
4       |2          |post       |que4      |ansA
5       |1          |railway    |que5      |ansB


tbl_ans
ans_id  |exam_type |answer |user_id |que_id
1       |1         |right  |001     |1
2       |1         |wrong  |001     |2
3       |1         |right  |002     |3
4       |1         |right  |002     |4



Output/result
|exam_type |question |answer   |correct_ans
|1         |que1     |right    |ansA
|1         |que2     |wrong    |ansC
|1         |que5     |NULL     |ansB
```

Comment: The problem is that you have `AND a1.user_id='001'`, now if there isn't an answer for the question, this `a1.user_id` will be null (due to the `LEFT JOIN`) so this condition will fail.

Comment: @NigelRen we were typing at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting the criteria for the user_id in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN ?

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6247eb/1/0)

```
select 
 q.exam_type,
 q.questions,
 a.answer,
 q.correct_ans
from tbl_que q
left join tbl_ans a on (a.que_id = q.que_id and a.user_id='001')
where q.exam_type = 1
order by q.que_id
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE t1.exam_type='1' AND (a1.user_id='001' OR a1.user_id IS NULL)
```

This will include in the results all questions from tbl_que that have no answers from any user (which thus includes user 001).

Output:

```
exam_type   questions   answer  correct_ans
1           que1        right   ansA
1           que2        wrong   ansC
1           que5        (null)  ansB
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/705c32/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this with left join:

```
select exam_type,questions,answer,correct_ans
from tbl_que a
left join tbl_ans b on a.que_id=b.que_id
where exam_type=1 AND (b.user_id='001' OR b.user_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked, I tried the same query but forgetting Parenthesis.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this by adding `user_id` condition in left join itself.

The below query should work for you.

```
SELECT 
    t1.exam_type, t1.questions, a1.answer, t1.correct_ans
FROM
    tbl_que t1
    LEFT JOIN  tbl_ans a1 ON a1.que_id = t1.que_id AND a1.user_id = '001'
WHERE
    t1.exam_type = '1' ORDER BY t1.que_id
```